# return at most 50 inserts in python/sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am aware of the function

```
cursor.lastrowid()
```

and this returns the last row. Im trying to return the last 50 inserts in my data base, how would one go about doing this?

Comment: Could You add some more details? Why don't You use plain SQL for this issue?

Comment: I'm obviously new to programming, next time ill also specify that as well

Answer (score 4):

use this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: @NubmcNub Because its a duplicate question.